# Spring Data JPA: How to create "delete by multiple properties" method?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to delete an entity(ies) by multiple entity properties?

I know how to do it using `JPA query` (`@Query` annotation).

Is It possible to do it using `derived query`? How to name such method in `JpaRepository`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is straight forward as naming select method:

Two properties:

```
long deleteByIdAndUser(
    @Param("id") Long id, 
    @Param("user") User user);
```

Three properties:

```
long deleteByIdAndUserAndStatus(
    @Param("id") Long id, 
    @Param("user") User user, 
    @Param("status") String status);
```

etc.

Comment: @Param("status") - is a "status" a column name or field name in my entity?

Comment: @Matley It is entity field name.

Comment: @MichalFoksa what's that returning 'Long'? is it the id of deleted user?

Comment: @wannix It is number of deleted entries. If you do not need that information, use `void` as a return type.

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks