# How to add a custom delete method in Spring boot Crud repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Is is possible to add a delete method that takes two conditions in CrudRepository?
For example,

```
deleteByUserNameAndId(String userName, String itemId)
```

Thanks and regards,
dj

Comment: Yes it is possible. Why wouldn't you even try it first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data JPA: How to create "delete by multiple properties" method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923434/spring-data-jpa-how-to-create-delete-by-multiple-properties-method)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data: "delete by" is supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723025/spring-data-delete-by-is-supported)